# First appearance of a condition in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe like this:

```py
    col
0   3
1   5
2   9
3   5
4   6
5   6
6   11
7   6
8   2
9   10
```

that could be created in Python with the code:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'col': [3, 5, 9, 5, 6, 6, 11, 6, 2, 10]
    }
)
```

I want to find the rows that have a value greater than `8`, and also there is at least one row before them that has a value less than `4`.

So the output should be:

```py
    col
2   9
9   10
```

You can see that index `0` has a value equal to `3` (less than `4`) and then index `2` has a value greater than `8`. So we add index `2` to the output and continue to check for the next rows. But we don't anymore consider indexes `0, 1, 2`, and reset the work.

Index `6` has a value equal to `11`, but none of the indexes `3, 4, 5` has a value less than `4`, so we don't add index `6` to the output.

Index `8` has a value equal to `2` (less than `4`) and index `9` has a value equal to `10` (greater than `8`), so index `9` is added to the output.

It's my priority not to use any *for-loops* for the code.

Have you any idea about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boolean indexing to the rescue:

```
# value > 8
m1 = df['col'].gt(8)

# get previous value <4
# check if any occurred previously
m2 = df['col'].shift().lt(4).groupby(m1[::-1].cumsum()).cummax()

df[m1&m2]
```

Output:

```
   col
2    9
9   10
```

Comment: I tried it with `df[df.groupby((df['col'].gt(8)).cumsum().shift(fill_value=0)).filter(lambda x: x.min() < 4).gt(8)].dropna()` but the output is coming out as `float`s instead of `int`. Any ideas why?

Comment: @MYousefi I can't try now, but if you had NaN the type changes to float. Use `convert_dtypes` to convert back to int (if possible).

Answer (score 1):

Check Below code using **SHIFT**:

```html
df['val'] = np.where(df['col']>8, True, False).cumsum()

df['val'] = np.where(df['col']>8, df['val']-1, df['val'])

df.assign(min_value = df.groupby('val')['col'].transform('min')).\
query('col>8 and min_value<4')[['col']]
```

OUTPUT:

[image]